# Error when using traefik to generate SSL certificate in aws elastic beanstalk

Tags: docker, ssl-certificate, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, traefik, lets-encrypt

I have a website running in AWS using elastic beanstalk service. I'm using docker to deploy it, by importing a docker-compose file that pulls and runs an image from my dockerhub repository. I also have a 53 route redirecting to my website, so it's working great until now. Here is my very simple docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  backend:
    image: "mypersonalrepo/image:tag"
    ports:
      - "80:8080"
    restart: "always"
```

The problem is that only works with http since I don't have any SSL certifcate, so I want to generate one.
I thought about using Traefik, because it seems like a good tool to use right now and use it with kubernetes in the future

I'm trying to use traefik to generate one certificate and redirect all traffic to my application, and this is what I'm trying to deploy:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  backend:
    image: "mypersonalrepo/image:tag"
    restart: "always"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.backend.rule=Host(`my.53.route.net`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.backend.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.backend.tls.certresolver=myresolver"
      - "traefik.http.services.backend.loadbalancer.server.port=8080"
    depends_on:
      - traefik


  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.9"
    container_name: "traefik"
    command:
      - "--log.level=DEBUG"
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
      - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.httpchallenge=true"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.httpchallenge.entrypoint=web"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.caserver=https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.email=myemail@gmail.com"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - "./letsencrypt:/letsencrypt"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
```

I'm getting errors when deploying it, but cannot understand what's going on. Maybe I need to add port 443 in my EC2 instance security group. And that is probably not enough, just feel a bit lost and don't know what the next steps are.

After I deploy it with the new docker-compose file, health will go to Severe condition

[image]

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: After I connect to ec2 machine, both services are running. And when checking traefik logs, I get this: 
`level=debug msg="No ACME certificate generation required for domains (my.53.route.net) `

This does not look like an error. But elastic beanstalk keeps failing

Comment: Edited inboud rules in EC2 instance to allow connections on port 80,443,8080. And when trying to connect to those ports, always get  "404 page not found"

Comment: Did you were able to solve it? I always get severe status when using traefik as a reverse proxy it works great if I use nginx. I think it is related to healthy checks.

Comment: How you have solved the healthy check error code when using traefik as a reverse proxy on elastic beanstalk with an application load balancer?